# Is there a way to make tree not show the top level?

Tags: tree

By default, `tree` shows this:

```
$ tree
.
├── Package.resolved
├── Package.swift
├── Sources
│   └── SwiftClientSDK
│       ├── OpenAPI.yaml
│       ├── SwiftClientSDK.swift
│       └── openapi-generator-config.yaml
└── Tests
    └── SwiftClientSDKTests
        └── SwiftClientSDKTests.swift
```

I would like for it to show the contents of the cwd like this:

```
Package.resolved
Package.swift
Sources
└── SwiftClientSDK
    ├── OpenAPI.yaml
    ├── SwiftClientSDK.swift
    └── openapi-generator-config.yaml
Tests
└── SwiftClientSDKTests
    └── SwiftClientSDKTests.swift
```

Nothing I see in the man page suggests this is possible.

Comment: Does it have to be a single invocation of `tree`? I think you could invoke `tree` from within `find`, for example.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't look like it

```
tree -- *
```

comes close, but it complains about those files that are not of type directory and follows symlinks to directories.

You could always post-process the output to remove that extra level of indentation:

```
tree -C | sed '1d;$!s/....//'
```

Here `d`eleting the `1`<sup>st</sup> line, and removing the first four characters (`s`ubstituting the first four characters with nothing) on all but (`!`) the last (`$`) line. `-C` option to `tree` is to keep the colours now that its output doesn't go to a terminal.

You could create a function for it:

```
ltree() (
  set -o pipefail
  if [ -t 1 ]; then
    set -- -C "$@"
  fi
  tree "$@" | sed '1d;$!s/....//'
)
```

Note that it won't work properly if passed more than one directory (as in `ltree dir1 dir2`). In that case, you likely want the normal `tree` output.

Comment: Yeah, I did something like that with `cut -c 5-`, which worked, but truncated the first bits of the summary line as well. Then I downloaded the source and started adding support for this feature directly ;)